# Ionic 2 Highcharts

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, highcharts, ionic2, highcharts-ng

I am using Ionic 2 framework and want to implement highcharts.

I followed this step https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-and-highcharts-modules/59365/2  from mharington (ionic team) to setup my first high chart.

The error I get is I can't import it but I installed with node modules

[image: Error]

[image]

```
 angular2-highcharts include in my node_modules
```

please help

Comment: If the answer below is not solving the problem for you, please check what script versions you are using.

Comment: is high charts in your package.json? I have added a lib before without adding the flag `--save` which then is not added to the package.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use HighChart in Ionic 2 you must:

- [installation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/installation)

  ```
  npm install highcharts --save
  ```
- Load module on the page where you want to use the charts

  ```
  declare var require: any;
  let hcharts = require('highcharts');
  require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(hcharts);`
  ```
- On the `activity.html` page

  ```
  <div #graph></div>
  ```
- and finally

  ```
  initLapChart() {
      hcharts.chart(this.div.nativeElement, {
          chart: {..}
      ... 
  }
  ```

I hope I was clear.

Comment: Thanks for helping

Answer (score 7):

You're probably using angular 2 RC. The answer from mharrington was about ionic beta.37 (i guess) which used a beta version of angular 2.

It's updated to `ChartModule` now. See below or check out the [github](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts) and their [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/IuwjpPB1YQW1T7i4B8SZ?p=preview) (plnkr)

As explained by the angular2-highcharts:

In your `@ngModule` declaration file (prob `app.module.ts`)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import { App } from './App';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, ChartModule],
    declarations: [App],
    bootstrap: [App]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and in your class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'simple-chart-example',
    template: `
        <chart [options]="options"></chart>
    `
})
export class App {
    constructor() {
        this.options = {
            title : { text : 'simple chart' },
            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
            }]
        };
    }
    options: HighchartsOptions;
}
```

Also, depending on what version you're using, you might have to change the import from

`import { ChartModule } from 'ng2-charts';`

To

`import { ChartModule } from 'ng2-charts/components/charts/charts';`

Because of [this issue (#440)](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/440#issuecomment-251671800)

*and keep in mind that the docs could be outdated, depending on version, if binding to `[datasets]` fails, bind to `[data]`* Source: [ng2-charts - Can't bind to 'datasets' since it isn't a known property of 'base-chart'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40301229/ng2-charts-cant-bind-to-datasets-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-base-c)